# Where can I find 8086 Emulator with I/O?

Tags: ide, emulation, simulator, x86-16

I have this wonderful emulator of the 8051 micro-controller with integrated simulation of peripheral devices also.
http://mcu8051ide.sourceforge.net/

Now, I have to program ***8086*** interfacing programs that interact with the peripheral devices and note the outputs.

Where can I find such an emulator with I/O devices? If anyone knows it

Answer (score 1):

You can download emu8086 emulator from [this link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/fa5bj44nwhid8pd/emu8086v408r.exe).

Comment: I was amazed by this program years back. Great you point this one out.